# Nuxt auth getToken witnin async is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to fetch some data from user and  I need to pass bearer token within call.

```
async asyncData () {
    let response = await axios.get('dataURL', {}, { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${this.$auth.getToken('local')}`} })
  },
```

But this doesn't work, it always says that $auth is undefined, while within template I can easily output any $auth property...

How can I get bearer token within async?

Comment: Make sure `this` is what you think it is.

Comment: @Titus Okay this is not usable within async. How can I get a cookie that is set from nuxt/auth module?

Comment: You can use `this` in an `async` function. You can set the function's context (what `this` refers to inside the function) using `bind` or `call` or `apply`. Here is an example: `someObject.asyncData.call(objectWith$authProp)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Titus is right that "this" is the issue. You don't have "this" available in asyncData because:

> You do NOT have access of the component instance through this inside
>   asyncData because it is called before initiating the component.

You do have access to "context" however so you can call the auth module using that:

```
async asyncData (context) {
    let response = await axios.get('dataURL', {}, { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${context.app.$auth.getToken('local')}`} })
  },
```

nuxtjs/Auth [docs](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth.html#properties)

However you are still not using asyncData as it should be because you're not returning anything that can be merged with data so you might want to try like this:

```
async asyncData (context) {
    let { response } = await axios.get('dataURL', {}, { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${context.app.$auth.getToken('local')}`} })
    return { token: response }
  },
```

Having said that, I don't really understand why you want to get your token in a component. Surely you are better off getting it globally through nuxtServerInit in your store.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to pass the context (this) , after your call?
E.g:

```
await axios.get('dataURL', {}, { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${this.$auth.getToken('local')}`} }),this;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
async asyncData (app) {
    let response = await axios.get('dataURL', {}, { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${app.$auth.getToken('local')}`} });
},
```

[Here](https://www.nuxtjs.cn/guides/concepts/context-helpers) is the documentation, you can learn more about it.